# Only FileSnoop can see my Win10 NTFS data file. Why?

Tags: window, ntfs

On a Win10 laptop, I have an application that writes data files to the C: root directory (DL900WIN, which is a home alarm security GUI).  The PC Magazine utility FileSnoop v1.1.0.0 can see it and confirms the name, size, file/date and attribute "A".  The filenames is "201207backup-DL900.DL1"

The Win10 File Explorer cannot see this file, even with "Hidden items" checked.
The Win10 CL dir does not show this file, with or without the /ah option.
The Win10 WSLinux does not show this file, even with the -a option.

If DL900WIN writes the file to a folder instead of C: root directory, then it is visible as a normal file should be. I can operate this way, but now I cannot delete the files in the C: root directory, so I'd like to learn.

What file system mechanism exists to hide a file in the root directory so that only FileSnoop (and DL900WIN) can see it? How can I access such a file with normal OS tools?

Comment: The file may not be created in C: root but somewhere else. This is done by a virtualization technique by Windows. Check if the file is under C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore. Also try this command and see if you find anything abnormal "fsutil volume filelayout <full path>"

Comment: Kamaal, Yes, I found them in the VirtualStore!  Is the OS doing this, or the App?  To copy/delete/rename, is a user expected to know about the VirtualStore?  Where can I read more?   For fsutil, are you saying to specify the full path to the file in the VirtualStore?  At the CL, I get "access denied".

Comment: The OS does this. This is done to prevent writing files directory to the root directory. Try running the application with elevated privileges. fsutil command requires administrative privilege. Yes you need to provide the actual path (VirtualStore)